# How to pass data and get specific details from an api call

Tags: angular

There's an api call for which the method is

```
   getServiceTimeZone() {
            return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.urlService.baseRestEndpoint + '/logcollection/getTimeZone');
        }
```

and urlService has:

```
export class UrlService {
  private origin: string;
  private basePath = '/webrtmt';
  private restBasePath = this.basePath + '/rest';

  constructor() {
    if (environment.host) {
      this._targetHostname = environment.host.split(":")[0];
    }
    this.origin = [this._protocol, '//', this._hostname, ':', this._port].join('')
  }



  public get baseRestEndpoint(): string {
    return this.origin + this.restBasePath;
  }
}
```

This is the current response:

[image]

This gives the timezone. Currently, I am getting the local timezone, I want to pass a server name and get that particular server timezone. How and where do I have to pass the server name?  I am not able to understand where do I have to pass the server parameter.

Comment: You would have to edit this on the back-end in the actual code that is running the API. Without seeing that code, we do not have enough information to answer this question. The API will have to be configured to return the time of the server the API is running on.

Comment: @cklimowski if I have to pass a parameter from the UI where I can send the server name, where will I have to do that?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for a way to do this for any API - that is, to get the local time of the currently responding server that is running the API that you are calling, using the server name as a parameter *without* configuring the API on the back-end server level code to do this...

I am not aware of a "default" way to get that information using only JavaScript because of the client to server relationship. The API would have to be configured to accept a parameter of a server name and return the local time based off of that.

EDIT: To answer your question in the comments, this is how I would do this in Angular, using the HttpParams import. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams

```
getServiceTimeZone(serverName: string): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
  let httpParams = new HttpParams().appendAll({
    server: serverName,
  });
  return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.urlService.baseRestEndpoint +
           '/logcollection/getTimeZone' {  
             params: httpParams, 
             observe: "response"
           });
    }
```

Which then makes a call like this:

```
api/logcollection/getTimeZone?server=serverName
```

Where "serverName" is the parameter you pass into the getServiceTimeZone function.

The corresponding API would have a controller function that has the serverName as a parameter, and uses the string value of the server name to run logic that returns the information you are looking for based off of that serverName.

Comment: Okay, So, as you mentioned `The API would have to be configured to accept a parameter of a server name and return the local time based off of that` , let's say for instance the api is configured as you mentioned, then in that case, how will have to pass the paramter with the server name. Can you please give an example code. Actually I am totally new to api, so I have no idea how this is done